# How to get RTMP URL

Tags: streaming, rtmp

I know this question was asked a lot, many of them were answered by viewing the source code, in my case it didn't work, using Internet Download Manager, i got the following link :

```
rtmp://178.162.202.6/live/fsdlfmlll2?id=247301&pk=a9930efdccdd78b9c127ef17a4150224b859aa6d3ec13c11129a10fd54edf7dd
```

This link is valid only on IDM, but on a player it's not, I'm trying to get the rtmp from [HERE](http://www.yalla-shoot.com/live/) (Press any streaming item, for updated links) .

The source code doesn't include anything related to rtmp, and the " Inspect Element / Network " is adding these :

```
http://www3.javabin.xyz/swf/57163b78560f4-7246945710.swf
http://www3.javabin.xyz/swf/833.m3u8?sf=NTcxNjNiNzg1NjBmNA==&token=M3mEC-3m9nJVB1WzLxTN4Q
```

Comment: Or a way to take that link and embed it in a player.

Comment: What programming language are you making the player with? Example : You want to embed in HTML5 video tag??? Or you need C++ code to extract RTMP data???

Comment: Actually I'm taking a ready code, which programmed in HTML5

Comment: IDM catch cookie of page that play video, if you want use that link you most attach the cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. The shown code can be previewed by testing **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro)**.

**(1)** Embed the video directy from DailyMotion (using i-frame) :

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="720" height="480"
src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x482s3s?autoplay=0">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Use `autoplay=1` if you want it to play automatically.

**(2)** Get URL from middle-man (a link downloader) :

The video you want is server-protected. That means here the server makes a temporary access token for each connection. One link today will not always work tomorrow because that token has expired. So each time you must know how to create a fresh token for access. Since that is difficut we use a next system (middle man) that can already do it for us....

For example using this downloader site as middle-man, **[GetVideo.at](http://getvideo.at/)**, you can get a JSON array of links by giving the url `http://getvideo.at/search?q=VIDEO_URL` where VIDEO_URL is your link to video page (Dailymotion, Youtube, Vimeo etc).

**(2.1)** 
So regarding your Dailymotion video that link looks like : 
**[`http://getvideo.at/search?q=http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x482s3s`](http://getvideo.at/search?q=http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x482s3s)**

When you got to that above link you get a JSON object (text) something like this:

```
{"video_formats": [{"quality": "240", "filename": "skipback_20160501_1600 (06).mp4", "url": "/download?id=064398ee-1d20-11e6-865b-06c0b400153d", "format": "mp4"}, {"quality": "384", "filename": "skipback_20160501_1600 (06).mp4", "url": "/download?id=064405a4-1d20-11e6-865b-06c0b400153d", "format": "mp4"}, {"quality": "480", "filename": "skipback_20160501_1600 (06).mp4", "url": "/download?id=06442dd6-1d20-11e6-865b-06c0b400153d", "format": "mp4"}, {"quality": "720", "filename": "skipback_20160501_1600 (06).mp4", "url": "/download?id=064462a6-1d20-11e6-865b-06c0b400153d", "format": "mp4"}], "thumbnail": "https://s1-ssl.dmcdn.net/Wp3_C.jpg", "audio_formats": [], "duration": "02:42", "title": "skipback_20160501_1600 (06)"}
```

**(2.2)** 
As you can see, for a **Quality : 240p** video the `URL` is : 
`/download?id=064398ee-1d20-11e6-865b-06c0b400153d`

So to play MP4 we combine `http://getvideo.at` with text extracted from shown `URL` from JSON. So the final link playable in HTML5 video tag (`src=`) is like this : 
**[`http://getvideo.at/download?id=064398ee-1d20-11e6-865b-06c0b400153d`](http://getvideo.at/download?id=064398ee-1d20-11e6-865b-06c0b400153d)**

**(2.3)** 
Use it as `<source src="http://rest of link"` when setting up the video tag.

```
<html> 
<body> 

<video id="myVideo" width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://getvideo.at/download?id=471c4a8a-1b24-11e6-9917-06c0b400153d" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p> Original Source : DailyMotion. </p>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.volume = 0.2;
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

**NOTE:** I don't use **Ruby**, to use this second method, your app must always check that **[`Getvideo.at`](http://getvideo.at/search?q=http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x482s3s)** link for a JSON of the correct links. JSON is just text... So either use Ruby's JSON parser or just use String functions to extract the link text. If you put that link to a String variable you can do something like below in the video tag: 
 
`<source src=$myLinkString type="video/mp4">`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hoped that you answered before the bounty expired, for the second method, what's "middle-man" ? i didn't find it, i found a Ruby framework, not a link downloader software.

Comment: I've edited to show how you can use a "middle-man" service to get the links. I don't use Ruby so I cant tell you how to extract the info, I've explained in detail so maybe you can do something with that. The important thing is to get that links text as response (maybe your Ruby app must appear like a browser request to their server?)

Comment: PS: No worries about the bounty. Maybe if you accept it can still be awarded, otherwise I think the system has actually swallowed it. I just answer cos is interesting question & I learnt something I might need one day..

Comment: I wish i can give you infinite upvotes, the awesome bounty system took the bounty and didn't hold it, I need the stream links only for 2 hours, so the expire limit isn't a problem for me. Thanks a lot for your detailed, awesome help! .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did something like this (looking in the HTML) to find the rtmp address:
https://msankhala.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/save-flash-player-video-rtmp-streaming-with-vlc-player/

I went four levels deep in iframes and I didn't find that address. Did you try on a VLC player?

Good luck.

Comment: I need to embed it in the iframe, not playing it on VLC player. I've tried to start it on VLC player, it worked yes, but in the iframe nope it didn't. also the links are dead now, I'm going to update them.